# Emit items after a period of time with RxJava

Tags: kotlin, rx-java

I want to emit items with RxJava after a period of time.
I've provided some pseudocode to make it clear, what I want

```
class Segment(
    val startTime: Int,
    val duration: Int
)

fun main() {
    val segments = listOf(
        Segment(0, 1500),
        Segment(1500, 3000),
        Segment(4500, 450)
    )
    
    Observable.fromIterable(segments)
        .period { segment ->
            waitFor = segment.duration // here we set a delay for the next item
        }
        .subscribe { segment ->
            doSomeWork(segment.startTime) // first item should be emmited immediatly
        }
}
```

Do you think I can make an elegant solution using Rx? What operators I should use. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my version `duration` in `Segment` object is the time to wait before emitting `startTime` (not the time to wait for the next item).

I've used `startWith` to emit the first item without any delay.

`concat` waits that each observable has been completed before subscribing to the next one, which maintains the order.

```java
@Test
public void so_delay() {

    List<Observable<Integer>> segments = Stream.of(
            new Segment(3, 1500),
            new Segment(4, 3000),
            new Segment(5, 4500)
    )
            .map(s -> Observable.just(s.startTime).delay(s.duration, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    Observable.concat(segments)
            .startWith(0)
            .blockingSubscribe(e -> System.out.println("------> :" + e));
}
```

*I'm using java sorry for that*